# Maintain One Set of objects to support multiple database Vendors (MS SQL, ORACLE etc)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, faas

I am designing a database framework (abstract back-end layer). I have to fulfill following requirements.

1) Can be used to configure with multiple database vendors (MS SQL, ORACLE)

2) Can't maintain multiple set of objects (stored procedures, views, functions) 
   according to database vendors (ms sql, oracle, my sql )

I have experience of developing database abstract layer to support multiple database vendors by changing configuration files.

But i had to maintain different set of objects(sp's,views) each time before ,according to database vendor.

Now the situation is different, I am thinking a out of the box way to implement current scenario.
If some one can give a good suggestion that would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: Do you mean one set of *database* objects? That is, one set of DDL for tables, views, stored procedures, etc?

Comment: Yes, It is hard to maintain same database objects in different vendor type databases . To overcome this issue i am trying to keep one set of database objects. Then Abstract layer will connect to common database object set.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is essentially too broad for StackOverflow, but I recommend you stick to basic ansi sql, just select/update/insert/delete. Not even create statements or limit/top etc. Eventually maybe.

You only need to look at the sheer number of different ORM libraries out there to know that this is not an easy problem to solve in a particular way and there is no magic bullet or revolutionary thinking that will make it so. If there was, someone else would have done it- they haven't, they've just had teams of people writing massive libraries to cope with a highly varied task

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i know it is too broad question, That is why i need some kind of guidance to implement this scenario.  ORM tool does not full fill my all requirements , specially 2nd requirement. I am thinking of using Function as a Service(FaaS) (Stored procedure as service ) approach. May be i will be wrong .But i believe there should be a proper way to implement this scenario.